# KrakenD - Adding custom header from a datastore to requests

Tags: krakend

We started to use KrakenD API Gateway, and we are trying to see how to do the following:

- At login, a service stores an object in Redis with the user id as the key (sub in a JWT)
- In subsequent requests, in addition to validating the JWT authentication token KrakenD would read from Redis and pass the stored data as a new header to the downstream service

It looks almost what Martian allows (https://www.krakend.io/docs/backends/martian/), but instead of static configuration, it would read that data from Redis to enrich the request headers

Is it possible without forking KrakenD?

Answer (score 0):

For almost any scenario, it is not necessary to fork KrakenD. In this case, you would need to create your request modifier plugin: https://www.krakend.io/docs/extending/plugin-modifiers/

The plugin would take care of that Redis connection and enriching the request to the backend.